# Check same name files in folder with different extensions, if exists, move one out

Tags: powershell, zip

Every morning, a folder gets the same named zip files transferred to it. I currently have script that will check for non-zipped files, and if they exist, an archive folder is created, and they are moved there. Then the zip files are unzipped and the then the zip file is deleted.

A new condition came in, that 1 file will not have a daily transfer, but it will be weekly (random day of the week), and that the associated non-zipped file must remain in the folder until that zip file is transferred in.

How would I rework my code to check the zipped file names against the non-zipped, and if there is a match, to move only those files before unzipping the rest?

My current code:
First `if` statement tests for non-existing zip files. If exists, a new archive directory is created with the date. Then those non-zips are moved to this folder.

Second `if` statement checks for zip files, if exists, it will unzip each one, then delete the zip files.

```
$dir = "D:\test"
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MMM-dd"

if (Test-Path "$dir\*" -Exclude *.zip -PathType Leaf) {
    $newDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Path "$dir\Archive\$date" -Force
    $nozip = gci -Recurse $dir -Exclude *.zip | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }

    foreach ($file in $nozip) {
        Move-Item $file $newDir
    }
}
if (Test-Path "$dir\*.zip" -PathType Leaf) {
    $list = gci -Recurse $dir -Include *.zip
    $shell = New-Object -COM Shell.Application

    foreach ($file in $list) {
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)
        foreach ($item in $zip.Items()) {
            $shell.NameSpace($dir).CopyHere($item)
        }
        Remove-Item $file
    }
} else {
    exit
}
```

Sample scenario:

Folder D:\Test contains files A.txt, B.txt and C.txt.
Every morning files B.zip and C.zip, containing a new B.txt and C.txt, are transferred to the same folder, D:\Test.

The zip files need to be unzipped, but the corresponding B.txt and C.txt that are already in this folder, need to be moved out to D:\Test\Archive, then B.zip and C.zip can be unzipped, leaving a new B.txt and C.txt in D:\Test, and then those zip files are deleted.

The piece I am having issues with, is that A.zip is not transferred daily.  It's once a week and until that A.zip hits the folder, A.txt needs to stay in D:\Test.

Right now, my script moves all non zip files to D:\Test\Archive every day.  So when B.zip and C.zip come into D:\Test, there will be no A.txt after the process is done, it is being moved to D:\Test\Archive with the rest of the files.

So I need a way to check all the .txt files against the .zip files, and if there is a match by file name, not the extension, then move that non zipped file to D:\Test\Archive.  If there is no match, leave that non zipped file in D:\Test and continue processing those that do match.

Comment: Consider adding some example scenarios with appropriate file names. Like so, `foo.zip arrives, there already are files bar and zof -> foo will be extracted and now there are files foo, bar...`

Comment: Ok, @vonPryz, I added the scenario of the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your first part like this:

```
$dir = "D:\Test"
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MMM-dd"
$newDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Path "$dir\Archive\$date" -Force
$files = (Get-ChildItem "$dir\*.txt").Name | foreach {$_.Split(".")[0]}
$zips = (Get-ChildItem "$dir\*.zip").Name | foreach {$_.Split(".")[0]}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    foreach ($zip in $zips)
    {
        if($file -match $zip)
        {
            Move-Item "$dir\$file.txt" $newDir
            Write-Output "$file matches $zip"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Output "$file does not match $zip"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Matt! I changed a few things up slightly, but your compare loops were key.

```
$dir = "D:\Test"
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MMM-dd"
$newDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Path "$dir\Archive\$date" -Force
$fileName = gci $dir -exclude *.zip | ? { ! $_.PSIscontainer} | % { [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) } | Sort
$zips = gci -recurse $dir -Include *.zip
$zipName  = $zips | % { [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) } | Sort

foreach ($file in $fileName){
    foreach ($zip in $zipName){
        if($file -match $zip){
            Move-Item "$dir\$file.txt" $newDir
        }
    }
}

if (Test-Path "$dir\*.zip" -pathType leaf){
    $shell = New-Object -com shell.application
    foreach($file in $zips){ 
       $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file.FullName)
       foreach($item in $zip.items()){
           $shell.Namespace($dir).copyhere($item)
       }   
       Remove-Item $file
    } 
} else {
  Exit
}
```